# WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater

Tags: scala, apache-spark

in my app spark streaming I received this error, when the app read a file stream.

```
 [error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 48 s, completed Jan 18, 2019 2:04:07 PM
sbt:project1> 19/01/18 14:04:10 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$24(Executor.scala:864)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2.run(Executor.scala:864)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find HeartbeatReceiver.
    at  org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postLocalMessage(Dispatcher.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:523)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:91)
    ... 12 more
```

I increase executor memory e network timeout

```
 .set("spark.executor.memory", "5g")
 .set("spark.network.timeout", "600s")
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: My first reaction would be to forget about it as you're running your Spark app in sbt so there could be a timing issue between threads of the driver and the executors. Unless you show what led to `Nonzero exit code: 1`, there's nothing I'd worry about.

Comment: Ok thanks but my app don't read a file like that

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that there is an issue with Spark's internal communication mechanism meaning the HeartbeatReceiver which is a component that receives heartbeat signals from executors to indicate that they are still alive.

This error can have different causes:

1. A network issue: for example if there is connectivity issue between the driver and the executors, the message may not be able to reach the HeartbeatReceiver.
2. A Driver overload problem: if the driver is overloaded with tasks, it may not be able to process the heartbeat in a timely manner.
3. Executor Timeout: if the task on the executor is taking too long to complete

You can try the following:
Increase the heartbeat interval by setting it to a higher value:
example : spark.conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "20s")

You can try increasing driver resources

spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.cores", "2")